# Find max and min of $IJ + FE + GH$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $D \in \triangle ABC$. Passing through *D*, contruct$\, FE \parallel AB, IJ \parallel AC, GH \parallel BC$. Find max and min of *IJ + FE + GH*
[image]

---

Can this problem be solved by AM-GM ? I tried $IJ + FE + GH \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\mid IJ\mid \cdot \mid FE\mid \cdot \mid GH\mid}$
and using $$\frac {FE}{AB} = \frac {CE}{CA}\implies FE = \frac {CE}{CA}\cdot AB\ ...$$
But still stuck

Comment: You may have to maximize a function of two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim: $$\frac{IJ}{AC} + \frac{ EF} { AB} + \frac{ GH} { BC} = 2. $$

Corollary:

$$ AB + BC + CA - \max(AB, BC, CA) \leq EF + GH + IJ \leq AB + BC + CA - \min(AB, BC, CA)$$

Proof of Corollary

$x, y, z$ are real numbers from 0 to 1 subject to $x+y+z$ = 2. $a,b,c$ are non-negative values. Then, the minimum and maximum value of $ax+by+cz$ is $a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)$ and $a+b+c-\min(a,b,c)$ respectively.

Apply this to $x = \frac{IJ}{AC}, y = \frac{EF}{AB}, z = \frac{GH}{BC}$, $a=AC, b=AB, c=BC$.

Proof of claim: Use similar triangles to show that $\frac{IJ}{AC} = \frac{IJ+BI+NJ} {AB+BC+CA}$. Combine fractions and show that the numerator is twice the denominator.

Hint: $IJ = ID+DJ = AE+ HC$.

---

This arose from considering the equilateral triangle, and realizing that it was a constant 2 throughout. The extremes in the scalene case is obtained by setting $D$ at an extreme point, i.e. a vertex.

Comment: Please make more detail, why $AB + BC + CA - \max(AB, BC, CA) \le EF + GH + IJ \leq AB + BC + CA - \min(AB, BC, CA)$ ?

Comment: @D3r0X4 If $x, y, z$ are real numbers from 0 to 1 subject to $x+y+z$ = 2, what is the min/maximum value of $ax+by+cz$? You should easily see that it's $a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)$ and $a+b+c-\min(a,b,c)$.

Comment: but if $D$ is a vertex, so that there are no parallel lines to $AB,BC,CA$. 
Example: $D \equiv A$, so that $FE \equiv AB, IJ \equiv AC\ ?$

--------------------------------

so D will be a point such that $AD = $ very very...small number ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with $D=A$. The sum will be $AB+BC$. This is still within the range. I don't see what your concern is.